# How to resolve CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' error

Tags: sql-server-express

The program is working fine when executed locally. But when I try to host it on a Virtual Machine and then execute it, the following error is coming.

> permission denied in database 'master' error

This is my connection string in appsettings.json :

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Server_Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;Integrated Security=True"
}
```

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough rights to create a database using integrated security. You can try to use an account to resolve this. In your connection string, instead of Integrated Security = True, use

```
 {
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Server_Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=DB_Name;User Id=sa;Password=yourpassword"
 }
```

take a look at :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the response. tried this change, its not making a difference. Also the site is published to a VM in Azure and the logged in user has dbadmin privilege in sqlexpress on the database as well as an administrator privilege on the VM. While running the app using visual studio on the VM there is no such issue and the same connection string works with Integrated security.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be solved by using the below connection strings:

CONNECTION strings:(will be present in appsettings.json)

1. for windows authentication

   ```
   Data Source=Machine_Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataBase_Name;Integrated Security=True
   ```
2. for SQL authentication

   ```
    Data Source=Machine_Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db_Name;User ID=saAccount;Password=MYPassword;Asynchronous Processing=True
   ```